# Click outside hide element

Tags: jquery

When I click on "Menu", ".submenu" toggle, I need when I click outside then ".submenu" should hide. I have used this in every div as like rows as like we use in app where it place at right side for edit delete.
 Thanks in advance.

HTML :

```
<div class="edit-goal-wrapper">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="account" >Menu</a>
                            <div class="submenu">
                                <ul class="root">
                                    <li ><a href="#" >Edit Target Date</a></li>
                                    <li ><a href="#" >Remove Goal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.edit-goal-wrapper .dropdown
{
    color: #555;
    margin: 0;

    right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.edit-goal-wrapper .submenu
{
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    width:150px;
    display:none;
}
.edit-goal-wrapper .dropdown li a
{
color: #555555;
display: block;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 6px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration:none;
}

.edit-goal-wrapper .dropdown li a:hover
{
background:#155FB0;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
.edit-goal-wrapper a.account 
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("icons/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 116px 17px;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    /*height: 28px;*/

    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 110;

}
.edit-goal-wrapper .root
{
border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-size: 12px; font-weight:normal;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 2px;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(".edit-goal-wrapper a").click(function(){

                    $(this).next().toggle();

                });
```

Comment: Also you can see this https://www.script-tutorials.com/click-action-css3-dropdown-menu-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the submenu when you click outside of it try:

```
$("body").click(function(e){
       if($('.submenu').find(e.target).length  == 0 && $(e.target).is(":not('.account')")) {
          $('.submenu').hide();
       } 
});
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/z134L2ab/2/

or

```
$("body").click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('.account')) {
           $('.submenu').toggle();
        } else if($('.submenu').find(e.target).length  == 0) {
           $('.submenu').hide();
        }
});
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/z134L2ab/3/

Comment: Can you explain in jsfiddle, please.

Comment: ok when you click on the page we test if the element in the page is found in the submeniu ,if the clicked element was not found  in the submeniu we hide the submeniu

Comment: Thanks friend for quick response, I tried but could not do it properly, I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/sdmh49wd/2/

Comment: Wow, Thanks madalin for your great help.